# what wrong with putExtra and string values

Tags: android, string

Ok....what's wrong with this?
Ive made a button...added this to the intent:

```
intent.putExtra("test","test");
```

then in onReceive had a little problem:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Log.v("Test", "Ok lets see");
String t=extras.getString("test");
Log.v("Test", "t="+t);
if(t=="test") t="tada";
else t="test";
Log.v("Test", "Ok...t="+t);
```

Now see the results from log

```
07-02 23:48:24.195    6278-6278/com.example.widget             V/Test: Ok lets see
07-02 23:48:24.205    6278-6278/com.example.widget             V/Test: t=test
07-02 23:48:24.205    6278-6278/com.example.widget             V/Test: Ok...t=test
```

Took me 1-2 hours to find out what was wrong with my code. Of course i have no idea what is wrong with the example above. My solution was to change from string to numbers (byte in my case). So after that everything was ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing Strings using `==`, which only works if they refer to the *exact* same object.

Use the `equals` method instead.

```
if(t.equals("test"))
    t = "tada";

Log.v(t) //Logs tada
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1286029) for more info.

Comment: You also can do `if ("test".equals(t))` which will protect against `NPE`